# Quitar texto de un select con JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

¿me pueden ayudar con una función que quite los textos de dos combos?
Los combos son los siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EL problema esta en que al eliminar la selección del combo País los otros combos (Estado y Municipio), deben limpiarse, es decir ya no debe mostrar Lima ni San Isidro. Ya lo intente y lo único que me sale bien es detectar que País ya se encuentra vacío. No se que atributos debo usar para que no me muestre los textos. Y este es el código:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $('#tblempleados-pais').on('change', function(){

        if($('#tblempleados-pais').val() == '' || $('#tblempleados-pais').val() == null){

            alert('entra');
            $('#tblempleados-estado').val('');
            $('#tblempleados-municipio').val('');

        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Debes mostrar el código con el que has intentado resolverlo !

Comment: Ya modifique la publicación, gracias por la corrección

Comment: prueba con   $("#tblempleados-estado").empty();

Comment: Acabo de hacer una prueba con tu código en el snippet de SOes y funciona correctamente, estas usando alguna librería para generar los selects?

Comment: Si de hecho si uso una libreria...deja busco la referencia la verdad no me acuerdo cual es

Comment: Es una extensión para Yii2 es Select2 así lo encontré Camilo Vasquez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin modificar tu JavaScript, agrega una opción en blanco a cada select. Ejemplo:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $('#tblempleados-pais').on('change', function(){

        if($('#tblempleados-pais').val() == '' || $('#tblempleados-pais').val() == null){

            alert('entra');
            $('#tblempleados-estado').val('');
            $('#tblempleados-municipio').val('');

        }

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
País <select type="text" id="tblempleados-pais"><br/>
<option></option>
<option selected="selected" value="Peru">Perú</option>

</select>
<br/>
Estado <select type="text" id="tblempleados-estado">
<option></option>
<option selected="selected" value="Lima">Lima</option>
</select>
<br/>
Municipio <select type="text" id="tblempleados-municipio">
<option></option>
<option selected="selected" value="San Isidro">San Isidro</option>
</select>
<br/>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y no estaría mal pero creo que es verdad que choca con una libreria

Comment: @Ivan92 ¿Ya lo probaste?

Comment: Si...lo que hiciste ya  y si funciona, es como debería pero en mi proyecto esos select los genero con una libreria y por eso tal vez no me jala como melo describes

Comment: Tal vez te falta pasarle a la librería como opción `''` (cadena vacía)

Answer (score 2):

Gracias a todos y tenia razón Camilo Vasquez era por la librería la respuesta era simple de igual forma pero nunca pensé que chocaría con eso. Es reemplazar esto:

```
$('#tblempleados-estado').val('');
$('#tblempleados-municipio').val('');
```

Por esto:

```
$("#tblempleados-estado").select2("val", "");
$("#tblempleados-municipio").select2("val", "");
```